# In 2 Peter 1:16 what does Peter mean by "eyewitnesses of his majesty"?

Tags: greek, word-study, 2-peter

> [2Pe 1:16-18 ESV] (16) For we did not follow cleverly devised myths when we made known to you the power and coming of our Lord Jesus Christ, but **we were eyewitnesses of his majesty**. (17) For when he received honor and glory from God the Father, and the voice was borne to him by the Majestic Glory, "This is my beloved Son, with whom I am well pleased," (18) we ourselves heard this very voice borne from heaven, for we were with him on the holy mountain.

What is an "eyewitness"? 
What is meant by "majesty"?

Answer (score 2):

**In 2 Peter 1:16 what does Peter mean by “eyewitnesses of his majesty”?**

Peter along with James and John were eyewitnesses to the transfiguration , in fulfillment of the prophetic word that was told to them six days earlier, that some of his followers would " not taste death until they see the kingdom of God after He has come with power.”( Mark 9:1) Thus Peter was able to inform his readers the power and presence of  our Lord Jesus Christ.

2 Peter 1:19 (NASB)

> 19" So we have the prophetic word made more sure, to which you do well
>   to pay attention as to a lamp shining in a dark place, until the day
>   dawns and the morning star arises in your hearts."

The  Majesty of  His Transfiguration.

Mark 9:1-7 NASB

> 1 And Jesus was saying to them, “Truly I say to you, there are some of
>   those who are standing here who will not taste death until they see
>   the kingdom of God after it has come with power.”
>
> 2 "Six days later, Jesus *took with Him Peter and [a]James and John,
>   and *brought them up on a high mountain by themselves. And He was
>   transfigured before them; 3 and His garments became radiant and
>   exceedingly white, as no launderer on earth can whiten them. 4 Elijah
>   appeared to them along with Moses; and they were talking with Jesus."
>
> 5 "Peter *said to Jesus, “Rabbi, it is good for us to be here; let us
>   make three [b]tabernacles, one for You, and one for Moses, and one for
>   Elijah.” 6 For he did not know what to answer; for they became
>   terrified. 7 Then a cloud [c]formed, overshadowing them, and a voice
>   [d]came out of the cloud, “This is My beloved Son, [e]listen to Him!”

Comment: Excellent and concise answer +1.  This is confirmed by the text in Peter that is a quote from the transfiguration incident.

Comment: What is an "eyewitness"? Is that a forensic term? And what is meant by "majesty"? Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at a Greek lexicon? G2030 ("eyewitness") is from the prefix G1909 and G3700 (to look/see).